# How can I display the top 10 entries per user in an Excel pivot chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel sheet where in there are 4 lebels. User Id, route_pair( kanpur to lucknow) and a revenue field. I want to create a chart where in i can show only top 10 routes and its revenue for a particular user_id. I do not want all the route pairs since its irrelevant for my analysis. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: Sorry. It is totally related to microsoft excel.

Comment: Which is an application, not a programming tool or language. SO is a Q&A site about programming

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot table.
User ID in Report filter and routes in routes in Rowfilter (Rows).
Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkfH2pvI84s